# Special character issue while fetching data from PostgreSQL to MS SQL Server, using linked server

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-server-2008, special-characters, collation

I am trying to fetch some user entered chanracter, in a filed, in postgre SQL table, into SQL Server using open query. But the data displaying is something different, and not as expected one.

The Expected is "Lomero, Fr->d->ric" but the value coming is as "Lomero, Fr�d�ric"

The special character "->" (Arrow as single spl character) is replaced with � (diamond with ?).
This special character (�) creating issue in our data processing.

The query I am currently using is as below,

```
select name   from openquery(IMAOCTEST,'select clna_client_name as name from XXX_schema.tblimaestro_sync_XXXX where 
clna_client_code in (66494)')
```

Is there any way to get the data as expected from PostgreSQL?
The linked server we created with the below options,

```
Collation Compatible - False
Collation Name - Null
Use Remote Collation - True
```

Comment: try to set postgresql client encoding to utf16

Comment: I hope utf16 not supported by the postgres client encoding. It throwing error.